# Tkinter is opening new windows when running a function in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, python-multithreading

Hi all I am using python 2.7.15 and tkinter. It is a simple GUI with some buttons. Once a button is pressed I need to start a function in a thread (I do not need to open any new windows).

What is happening is for each thread a new GUI copy of the program is opened. Is there any way to start a function (that does some calculations) without popping up a new copy of the Tkinter gui?

I am making a thread like this:

```
thread = Process(target=functionName, args=(arg1, arg2))
thread.start()
thread.join()
```

EDIT: here is some code to reproduce. As you can see, all I am interested in below "sample" is to run one function. Not to clone the whole program.

```
from Tkinter import *
from multiprocessing import Process

window = Tk()

window.title("Test threadinng")

window.geometry('400x400')


def threadFunction():
    sys.exit()

def start():
    thread1 = Process(target=threadFunction)
    thread2 = Process(target=threadFunction)
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()

btn = Button(window, text="Click Me", command=start, args=())

btn.grid(column=1, row=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Thank you.

Comment: We can't know why it's popping up a new window without seeing the definition of `functionName` - can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It doesn't have to be your real code, just the minimal code that still reproduces your issue.

Comment: `multiprocessing.Process` is not a thread.  It's a process.  Were you intending to use `threading.Thread`?

Comment: @RandomDavis (edited and added)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I believe thread is slow? I dabbled a little bit with it and threading would run all threads on the same CPU core. I need this to be fast (doing lots of calculations), ultimately I do not care if I use Thread or Process, whichever would be faster parsing hundreds of files with soup. I am new to python and Tkinter, so forgive my ignorance in the subject. Is the issue I am having with windows opening up a byproduct of using Process and there is no way around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the child process will inherit resource from parent process, that means it will inherit tkinter from parent process.  Put the initialization of tkinter inside `if __name__ == '__main__'` block may solve the problem:

```
from tkinter import *
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def threadFunction():
    print('started')
    time.sleep(5)
    print('done')

def start():
    thread1 = Process(target=threadFunction)
    thread2 = Process(target=threadFunction)
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread1.join()
    thread2.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Test threadinng")
    window.geometry('400x400')
    btn = Button(window, text="Click Me", command=start)
    btn.grid(column=1, row=1)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you!